# How to change orientation of axis in Blender?

Tags: axis

I'm trying to get parity between the axis orientation between UE4/UE5 and Blender and I am noticing that the two programs flip +X with -X. Observe my image. Is it possible to change the orientation of the axis in Blender?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, Blender is based on a Z-up Cartesian-Right orientation which is meant for maximum compatibility with CAD softwares and cannot be changed within blender. If you need special orientations for your exported objects, most of the export formats have options that allow you to export to different coordinate systems (ie Y-up, -X forward, etc...).